# EFCore BulkInsert with one to one relationship

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use bulkinsert from EFCore.BulkExtensions in .NET Core 2.1 with one to one relationships. I have 2 Database Entities

```
public partial class Entity1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Entity2 Entity2Obj { get; set; }
}

public partial class Entity2 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Entity1_ID{ get; set; }
    public virtual Entity1 Entity1Obj { get; set; }
}
```

Then I insert a list of Entity1 Items

```
 _context.BulkInsert(Entity1ItemsList);
```

This only works and inserts Entity1 objects in my database. The associated Entity2  items are not inserted. Is there a way to achieve that?

The navigation properties are automatically created during Scaffold-DbContext (database first)

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.Entity1 )
    .WithOne(p => p.Entity2)
    .HasForeignKey<Entity2>(d => d.Entity1_ID)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
    .HasConstraintName("FK_Entity1_Entity2");
```

Comment: Have you set data on each  `Entity1ItemsList` item for `Entity2Obj ` ?

Comment: Here's the rule of thumb: Make sure your relationships are configired correctly between `Entity1` and `Entity2` ... This might mean configuring them with FluentAPi since you have navigation properties... Secondly ensure that all object in `Entity1ItemsList` ave data passed to `Entity2Obj`

Comment: Yes there is data for each Entity2Obj  item in  Entity1ItemsList. The relationships are automatically set during Scaffold-DbContext as it is database first. If I use the context.Add() for each item of the Entity1ItemsList with context.SaveChanges() then the navigation properties are populated successfully. So I think that the relationships  are configured correctly. It does't work only with bulkinsert.

Comment: The relationships are automatic by convention but this is not always the case. Especially after realizing that your `Entity2` doesn't have a nav property back to `Entity1`.

Comment: Can you adding `IncludeGraph` option and set it to true? ... refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching around I think I found the solution. First of all set the following config

```
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig()
{
    SetOutputIdentity = true,
    PreserveInsertOrder = true
};
```

Run the initial bulkconfig to insert the Entities1List and get the unique IDs from SQL Server

```
_context.BulkInsert(Entity1ItemsList, bulkConfig);
```

Now the unique primary keys are assigned so to set their values to their related entities use

```
foreach (var item in Entity1ItemsList)
{
    item.Entity2Obj.Entity1_ID = item.ID;
}
```

This will set the correct Foreign Key values. Then I BulkInsert the Entities2List

```
var Entities2List = Entity1ItemsList.Select(u => u.Entity2Obj).ToList();
 _context.BulkInsert(Entities2List);
```

I was hoping for something simpler by using only one BulkInsert which will automatically add all the navigation properties instead of 2. But this works and it's fast.

Comment: Any updates on this? EF core does it out of the box

Comment: The only working way I found which I am still using is the one I mention, in a c# Asp.net mvc project using entity framework 6.2.0 and Taneryd.Bulkoperation.EF6. I will the EF Core's way (as you mention) if I ever migrate the project to asp.net core which I think is a better solution

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for since you also want to insert child properties.

`context.BulkInsert(Entity1ItemsList, options => options.IncludeGraph = true);`

You can read further [here](https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-insert#insert-with-related-child-entities-include-graph):

Comment: I am not using this BulkInsert. I am using the one from here https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions as the one you are using is not free! So i cannot use the IncludeGraph  as it is not available. I also edited my question with the property back to entity as I forgot to mention it